# jQUery UI dialog - modal creates scrollbars, wrong dimension?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, scrollbar, modal-dialog

I'm currently working on a site that uses ajax to load the content into a jQuery UI modal dialog.

On Win7 Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera it works fine.

On Internet Explorer 7-9pp and on mac firefox, chrome, safari and opera, the size of the modal background layer seems to be calculated wrong and creates vertical and horizontal scrolling until you resize the browser.

I uploaded the current demo version here: 
 - (removed to free some webspace on my server, see comments/answers for details on the problem/solution )

the basic layout is something like this

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">header, navigation, footer and stuff</div>
  <div class="ui-dialog"></div>
  <div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div>
</body>
```

with the following styles

```
html { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; }
body { display: block; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-widget-overlay { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

Thanks in advance for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your `HTML` tag, in css file style.css there is `overflow-y:scroll`. Remove it and add `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: and what about users with small resolutions?

Comment: @kadd_lancer you are correct, it's better to add `overflow:auto` instead `overflow:hidden` to show the scrollbar only when is required (for example small screens)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that tomorrow and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:hidden` did nothing for me, even if I opened Chrome's developer tools and manually added it, or tried to make it important:

```
style="overflow:hidden !important"
```

What *did* get rid of those annoying scrollbars, when a jQuery Dialog was displayed, was to add this CSS:

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
}
```

Simple, hey ?

It's just strange that jQueryUI doesn't include this by default...